# Making a literal to apply members as variables inside a function

Tags: javascript, extjs4

Im passing to a function a literal as a configuration object, like:

```
configureGrid: function (config) {
    var editable = config.editable,
        dbName = config.dbName,
        tableName = config.tableName,
        grid = config.grid,
        callback = config.callback;
    var storeFields,
        gridColumns,
        store;

    if (editable) {
        this.makeGridEditable(grid);
    }
    ...
```

Now, id like to know if there is a better way to get each member of the configuration object and define it as a variable inside the function.

I know i could just reference the members as config.memberName, but for clarity id prefer not.

Comment: I think you'll have to do it manually. There's no dynamic way to set variables inside a function because you can't access its scope object. You can for a global var with `window.memberName` but not for functions.

Comment: why do you need each as a variable?  `this.makeGridEditable(config.grid)`

Comment: FYI, in ECMAScript 6 you'll be able to use destructuring assignment. Works right now in Firefox. `var {editable,dbName,tableName,grid,callback} = config;` If the property names differ from the property names, you'd need to specify them in the declaration syntax. `var {editable:foo, dbName:bar...} = config;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you might want to use the JavaScript `with` feature.

I tested it in Firebug like this:

```
var stuff = {
  a: 'apple',
  b: 'banana',
  c: 'crepe',
  d: 'dinosaur'
};

with (stuff) {
  alert(b + ' ' + c); // alerts "banana crepe"
}
```

It's not exactly a recommend feature to use, but you can read more about it here: [MDN - with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)